# TFS - Not able to configure reporting services : Edit option no visible

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to configure reporting services in TFS 2015, but there no **Edit** link visible on TFS Administration console.

I have upgraded server from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015.

.
[image: There should be Edit link at red rectangle box, but it is not visible in my case.]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have configured below settings before adding a report server.

> Q: What kind of report server can I add?
>
> A: You'll need to add SQL Server Reporting Services to provide a
>   report server for TFS. This can be added to the SQL Server instance
>   that is supporting TFS, or to a different instance.
>
> Q: What permissions do I need?
>
> A: You need to **be a member of the local administrators group** on the
>   server, **the Team Foundation Administrators group in TFS**, and **the
>   sysadmin group in SQL Server**, or have the equivalent permissions.

Also note:*If you installed TFS on a client operating system, such as Windows 7, you can't add reporting as described here, because it isn't supported on client operating systems.*

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have given all the access rights as you suggested.